# Livewire/Laravel - how to reference id of parent table and child table

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How can one display, or at least seperate, the id of the parents vs the child?

To keep things simple, I will display my controller and then the view.

Controller:

```
public function render() 
{
     return view('pageDisplay', [
        <!-- Parent is main table. Child is secondary table -->
        'Parent' => ParentModel::
        join('Child', 'Parent_FK', '=', 'Child.id')
        ->get()
    ]
}
```

Here is my view:

```
    @foreach($Parent as $post)
        <!-- How to display last current parent id as well as separate id??? -->    
        Child id: {{ $post->id }}
        Parent id: ???
    @endforeach
```

Comment: You'll have an easier time if you use real Eloquent relationships, so you can do `foreach($parent->posts as $post)`. I suspect the join, as implemented, will mess up IDs, as both your parent and child tables have an ID column.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I had No idea you could specify keys in the eloquent relationship!

Comment: How could you reference the child id?

Comment: On your `Parent` model, you'd define a `public function children() { return $this->hasMany(Child::class); }`. Your children would need a `parent_id` column. Read https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For whatever reason I had it reversed. When I use $post->id, it displays the Child id, not the Parent id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two models, let's call them **ParentModel** and **ChildModel**, and there is a one-to-many relationship where one parent can have multiple children. Here's a basic example:

**Define the Models:**

**ParentModel.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ParentModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'parent_table';

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChildModel::class);
    }
}
```

**ChildModel.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ChildModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'child_table';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ParentModel::class);
    }
}
```

**Migration:**

Ensure that the child table migration includes a foreign key column:

**CreateChildTable.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('child_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        // Other child table columns
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_model_id');
        $table->foreign('parent_model_id')->references('id')->on('parent_table');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Usage in Livewire Component:**

Assuming you have a Livewire component where you are working with these models:

**YourLivewireComponent.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\ParentModel;

class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        // Fetch parent model with its children
        $parent = ParentModel::with('children')->get();

        return view('livewire.your-component', [
            'parent' => $parent,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your Livewire Blade view, you can then loop through the children and access their IDs:

```
<!-- livewire/your-component.blade.php -->
<div>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($parent as $value)
            <li>Parent ID: {{ $value->id }}</li>
            @foreach ($value->children as $children)
              <li>Child ID: {{ $children->id }}</li>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```